# SQL Select Columns that Only Allow Unique Values

Tags: sql-server

When querying an SQL Server database for database structure information, how do you determine if a column is required to be unique?

Before you answer, note that this question isn't about `DISTINCT` which would return rows of data, but rather about the table structure itself.

I also know that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` gives a list of unique constraints applied explicitly to columns.  However, I noticed that it didn't include primary keys. I could create a join with a subquery that gets primary key information, but would that be comprehensive?

So how do you know *for sure* that a column must be unique?

Comment: You could always try to insert a duplicate value. That way you are pretty sure.

Comment: I think if you got unique constraints, unique indexes and primary keys, that would cover it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query

```
select s.name, t.name, i.name, c.name
 from sys.tables t
inner join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
inner join sys.indexes i on i.object_id = t.object_id
inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.object_id = t.object_id
    inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id and
        ic.column_id = c.column_id
where i.index_id > 0    
and (i.is_unique_constraint = 1 or i.is_unique = 1)
```